# Change password on devise user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to build a custom reset password functionality. 
I have a form on my view

```
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :password %>
     <%= f.password_field :password, autofocus: true, title:"Enter your email", name:"password", id:"password", class:"form-control" %>
      <span class="help-block small">Password</span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
       <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autofocus: true, title:"Enter your email", name:"password_confirmation", id:"password_confirmation", class:"form-control" %>
        <span class="help-block small">Confirm Password</span>
      </div>
   <div class="actions"><%= f.submit "Update Password", class:"btn btn-success btn-block" %></div>
```

Then on my controller I am trying to change the password and password_confirmation fields.

```
 @user.update_attributes({:password => params[:password], :password_confirmation => params[:password_confirmation]})
```

it seems that the password is changing but when I am trying to login I can't !

Comment: Please post the full snippet of erb including the <%= form_for tag

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be referencing the posted parameters directly within params, rather than through the strong parameters reference that has permitted their submission.

For example the strong parameters definition in your controller should probably be something like

```
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:password, :password_confirmation)
end
```

Then refer to the parameters with `user_params[:password]`, etc, rather than params directly.

This has the dual effect that only whitelisted parameters are accepted, and that the user[password] and user[password_confirmation] parameters are more easily accessible.